# Spring boot websocket configuration error

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket, stomp

> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurationSupport.messageBrokerTaskScheduler()'

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
 public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("https://localhost.com").withSockJS();
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/aq-topic", "/aq-queue");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/aq-broker");
}

@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration channelRegistration) {
    channelRegistration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(4).maxPoolSize(8);
}

@Override
public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration channelRegistration) {
    channelRegistration.taskExecutor().corePoolSize(4).maxPoolSize(8);
}

}
```

Here is the Attached Screenshot

[image]

Comment: clean your .m2 repo and rebuild again...!

Comment: @gnanajeyam95 tried that already, still getting this strange issue

Comment: For what it's worth, I think [this article](https://reflectoring.io/nosuchmethod/) would have helped you solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There was and additional dependency added in pom.xml file of activeMQ and hence AbstractMessageBrokerConfiguration class was getting picked from active-mq-all.jar instead in should be picked up from simp/spring-messaging.jar.

Removing external Active mq dependency has solved my problem.

Comment: If this is the correct answer please mark it as such to help users who may run into this issue in the future.